# How to subtract the int values within 2 UITextFields

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have a IBAction UILabel to add a number every time it is pressed. I have a Total UITextField that a adds all 3 UILabels. Getting the total seems to be fine until I hit the subtract(buttonTap2) UILabel button.
Here is an example of  the IBAction UILabel code not working:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTap2:(id)sender {
    int value = [currentLabel.text intValue] - 1;
    currentLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",value];

    int n1 = [label2.text intValue]; // total labels
    int n2 = [label3.text intValue];
    int n3 = [label4.text intValue];
    int s = n1 - n2 - n3;
    NSString *sn = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",s];
    [tex7 setText:sn];
```

Comment: (1) Try and keep newlines and tabbing similar to your source when posting. (2) What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What problem are you having? What is "tex7"? If it's supposed to be a textfield or label, is it correctly linked up in Interface Builder? You might have missed it as it isn't very descriptive.

Comment: 'tex7' is the name of the UITextField. Everything succeeds with the app. The trouble I'm having is when I press the UILabel(buttonTap2) to subtract a number from a UITextField, it's making my total output negative. exmaple:

Comment: NSLog the results of n1, n2 and n3.

Comment: How would I go about adding the NSLog? could you give an example?

Comment: Before the 'int s' line add NSLog(@"%d %d %d", n1, n2, n3). This will tell you the current values of those variables, so you can debug them easier.

Comment: Ok, here is where I stand. I need this UIButton code to subtract one from a UITextField that is selected.

Comment: The problem is, the problem isn't obvious by the code snippet. I suggested doing those logs so we could get a better understanding of the state of the code. Alternatively, email me with a zipped project and I'll be happy to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you only get negative values if n1n2>n3. If you want to convert negative numbers to positive number then you take mode of the number ,what ever the number is converted in to Positive number. Another thing you do is that compere the resultant number if it is less then 0 then multiple it with -1,